# How do I correctly pass a Collection from my form to a JS event handler and then to a REST controller?

Tags: java, html, jquery, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to rewrite my forms in a way that doesn't involve any page refreshing. In other words, I don't want the browser to make any GET/POST requests on submit. jQuery should help me with that.
Here's my form (I have a few of them):

```html
    <!-- I guess this action doesn't make much sense anymore -->
    <form action="/save-user" th:object="${user}" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${user.id}">
    
         <input type="hidden" name="username"
              th:value="${user.username}">
    
         <input type="hidden" name="password"
              th:value="${user.password}">
    
         <input type="hidden" name="name" th:value="${user.name}">
    
         <input type="hidden" name="lastName"
              th:value="${user.lastName}">
    
         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="departments">Department: </label>
              <select id="departments" class="form-control"
                       name="department">
                  <option th:selected="${user.department == 'accounting'}"
                          th:value="accounting">Accounting
                  </option>
                  <option th:selected="${user.department == 'sales'}"
                          th:value="sales">Sales
                  </option>
                  <option th:selected="${user.department == 'information technology'}"
                          th:value="'information technology'">IT
                  </option>
                  <option th:selected="${user.department == 'human resources'}"
                          th:value="'human resources'">HR
                  </option>
                  <option th:selected="${user.department == 'board of directors'}"
                          th:value="'board of directors'">Board
                  </option>
              </select>
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="salary">Salary: </label>
              <input id="salary" class="form-control" name="salary"
                     th:value="${user.salary}"
                     min="100000" aria-describedby="au-salary-help-block"
                     required/>
              <small id="au-salary-help-block"
                     class="form-text text-muted">100,000+
              </small>
          </div>
    
          <input type="hidden" name="age" th:value="${user.age}">
    
          <input type="hidden" name="email" th:value="${user.email}">
    
          <input type="hidden" name="enabledByte"
                 th:value="${user.enabledByte}">
          
          <!-- I guess I should JSON it somehow instead of turning into regular strings -->
          <input type="hidden" th:name="authorities"
                 th:value="${#strings.toString(user.authorities)}"/>
    
          <input class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" type="submit"
                 value="Submit">
      </form>
```

Here's my JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', async function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let user = {
            id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
            username: $('input[name=username]').val(),
            password: $('input[name=password]').val(),
            name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
            lastName: $('input[name=lastName]').val(),
            department: $('input[name=department]').val(),
            salary: $('input[name=salary]').val(),
            age: $('input[name=age]').val(),
            email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
            enabledByte: $('input[name=enabledByte]').val(),
            authorities: $('input[name=authorities]').val()

            /*
            ↑ i tried replacing it with authorities: JSON.stringify($('input[name=authorities]').val()), same result
            */
        };

        await fetch(`/users`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                ...getCsrfHeaders(),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user) // tried body : user too
        });

    });
});

function getCsrfHeaders() {
    let csrfToken = $('meta[name="_csrf"]').attr('content');
    let csrfHeaderName = $('meta[name="_csrf_header"]').attr('content');

    let headers = {};
    headers[csrfHeaderName] = csrfToken;
    return headers;
}
```

Here's my REST controller handler:

```java
    // maybe I'll make it void. i'm not sure i actually want it to return anything
    @PutMapping("/users")
    public User updateEmployee(@RequestBody User user) {
        service.save(user); // it's JPARepository's regular save()
        return user;
    }
```

The `User` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column
    private String department;
    @Column
    private int salary;
    @Column
    private byte age;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private byte enabledByte;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "role")})
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

The `Role` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String authority;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<User> userList;
```

When I press the submit button, I get this in my console

```
WARN 18252 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.HashSet<pp.spring_bootstrap.models.Role>` from String value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_STRING`)]
```

It seems I should somehow pass a JSON representation of that `Collection`, not just a `String`. In my previous project, without the use of jQuery, the `String` was successfully deserialized with my custom `Formatter`

```java
@Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(new Formatter<Set<Role>>() {
            @Override
            public Set<Role> parse(String text, Locale locale) {
                Set<Role> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
                String[] roles = text.split("^\\[|]$|(?<=]),\\s?");
                for (String roleString : roles) {
                    if (roleString.length() == 0) continue;
                    String authority =
                            roleString.substring(roleString.lastIndexOf("=") + 2,
                                    roleString.indexOf("]") - 1);
                    roleSet.add(service.getRoleByName(authority));
                }
                return roleSet;
            }

            @Override
            public String print(Set<Role> object, Locale locale) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

I googled, and it appears Thymeleaf doesn't have any `toJson()` method. I mean I can write my own methods, but I don't know how to use them in Thymeleaf templates anyway. Besides, [it may not be the most optimal solution](https://xyproblem.info/)

It's a Boot project so I have that Jackson databind library

**How do I correctly pass a Collection from my form to a JS event handler and then to a REST controller?**

I examined multiple similar questions suggested by StackOverflow. They don't appear relevant (for example, they involve different programming languages, such as C# or PHP)

**UPD:** I tried this just now. It's a pitty it didn't work too! (the error message is the same)

```java
// inside my config
    @Bean
    public Function<Set<Role>, String> jsonify() {
        return s -> {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ", "{", "}");
            for (Role role : s) {
                sj.add(String.format("{ \"id\" : %d, \"authority\" : \"%s\" }", role.getId(), role.getAuthority()));
            }
            return sj.toString();
        };
    }
```

```html
    <input type="hidden" th:name="authorities" 
           th:value="${@jsonify.apply(user.authorities)}"/>
```

The method works as expected, though

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', async function (event) {
        /*
        ↓ logs:
          authorities input: {{ "id" : 1, "authority" : "USER" }}
        */
        console.log('authorities input: ' + 
                   $('input[name=authorities]').val());
```

**UPD2:** GPT4 suggested this

```js
authorities: JSON.parse($('input[name=authorities]').val())
```

and now it's really weird. The database is still unchanged, BUT! the IDE console now has no errors and no mentioning of a PUT request at all (it was there on previous attempts)! Additionally, the browser log has this message

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (script.js:28:31)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.slim.min.js:2:43114)
    at v.handle (jquery.slim.min.js:2:41098)
```

I don't know what it means!

**UPD3:** GPT4 is smart. Smarter than me, anyways. It was absolutely right. The reason it didn't work in UPD2 was the fact that I ignored another thing it said:

> The authorities field should be sent as an **array** of objects rather than a string.

It means I was supposed to use square brackets, not curly brackets, as my `StringJoiner` prefix and suffix:

```java
    // I also added some line breaks, but I doubt it was necessary
    @Bean
    public Function<Set<Role>, String> jsonify() {
        return s -> {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",\n", "[\n", "\n]");
            for (Role role : s) {
                sj.add(String.format("{\n\"id\" : %d,\n\"authority\" : \"%s\"\n}", role.getId(), role.getAuthority()));
            }
            return sj.toString();
        };
    }
```

I also changed, for example, this

```js
username: $('input[name=username]').val()
```

to this (it was silly of me not to do it right away)

```js
username: $(this).find('input[name=username]').val()
```

and – viola – it works now!

And GPT4 also noticed I used

```js
'input[name=department]'
```

instead of

```js
'select[name=department]'
```

I fixed that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It should be an array of objects (even though it's a `Collection`, not an array) so

`new StringJoiner(", ", "{", "}")` → `new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]")`

2. It should target the form's children so

`username: $('input[name=username]').val()` → `username: $(this).find('input[name=username]').val()` or better still `username: $(this).find('[name=username]').val()` and so on

3. `department` is represented by a `<select>` element so

`'input[name=department]'` → `'select[name=department]'` or `'[name=department]'`